# How does kubernetes maintain the deployment yaml internally. Where will be it stored after the first deployment

Tags: kubernetes

Once you deploy a pod, kubernetes monitors the pod health and if something goes wrong, new pod is created . How is this working internally. After deployment, where is kubernetes storing the deployment yaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes uses the ETCD database as data store. The flow is like this. Kubectl command connect to API server and sends the yaml file to API server.  API parses and store the information in ETCD database.  Kube controller and schedule looks at the ETCD database and starts the POD. Controller maintain the number of replica defined in the yaml file.

Comment: we need to use the kubectl command to get the pod information. eg. this command will give pod information in yaml format `kubectl get pods <podname> -o yaml `.  store the output in the file and make the changes then use `kubectl apply -f <filename>`

Comment: Thank you . very helpful info. :)

Comment: _strictly speaking_, the API always uses json -- and since yaml is [a superset of JSON](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572), any yaml input is reduced to JSON before transmission by `kubectl`. You can see this in action with `kubectl --v=100` (which itself is fascinating to see, and also emits \[mostly\] `curl`-compliant invocations). Also pedantically, `kubelet` starts Pods, but you are correct `kubelet` does this at the direction of the scheduler